# What is the best way of handling a new PaymentIntent in Laravel Cashier

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Unless I'm missing something, I cannot see any Cashier wrapper to provide the creation of a PaymentIntent, does this exist?

While Cashier v10 added some content to handle SCA it doesn't work for me because I am handling payment details via a font-end element, so redirecting to a new `route` is messy.

I need to handle it as per this guide https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration

Which requires the creation of a PaymentIntent like so:

```
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'payment_method' => $json_obj->payment_method_id,
    'amount' => 1099,
    'currency' => 'gbp',
    'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
    'confirm' => true,
]);
```

I can of course do this directly from the Stripe sdk as shown here, but given I am likely to add more functionality that will likely make use of Cashier's other features it would keep it cleaner to go through Cashier for everything.

Can I create a PaymentIntent via Cashier or has that been missed off? If so, how? Or should I be handling this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having investigated this further, the answer is that the

```php
Laravel\Cashier\Billable->charge($amount,$method,$options)
```

method does a `\Stripe\PaymentIntent::create($options)` under the covers.

There are some things to be aware of:

- By default the options `confirmation_method` will be set to `automatic` and `confirm` to `true`
- The `currency` option will be set and will use the Cashier default currency
- The `amount` option will be set based on the `$amount` passed in and the `payment_method` option will be set based on the `$method` passed in.
- These values can all be overridden with replacements by passing an equivalent value in the `$options` argument

And finally, if you require [SCA](https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication/doineed) (which I did) then you must catch a `\Laravel\Cashier\Exceptions\PaymentActionRequired` exception and either redirect to the built-in `Cashier` page for this, or handle it in your front-end via your API request.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Cashier user but it looks to be an interface to Stripe Billing, so it mostly handles primitives related to Billing.
From what I can tell, it does use PaymentIntents under the hood (for authenticating invoice payments that require authentication) but doesn't expose PaymentIntent creation directly.

The Cashier docs recommend that your integration redirect to the "payment page" when authentication is required: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/billing#payments-requiring-additional-confirmation (for cases where PaymentIntents are in state `requires_action`)

For creating PaymentIntents directly, the stripe-php API library would be the right approach.

Comment: Thanks for responding, the Laravel docs approach of redirecting does not work for me because I am handling the process all via the front end using API, that's why I need the paymentIntents approach from the Stripe documentation.  However Cashier does not appear to support createPaymentIntent, hence my question, is there a way still to do it with PaymentIntent?

Comment: Doesn't seem so with Cashier, you can use Stripe-PHP instead, it would allow you to use all Stripe resources including creating PaymentIntents: 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=php

Answer (score 1):

Extend the Laravel\Cashier\Billable Trait;
and Laravel\Cashier\Concerns\PerformsCharges;
and use it instead of the default Billable trait in the User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits\Stripe;

use Laravel\Cashier\Concerns\ManagesCustomer;
use Laravel\Cashier\Concerns\ManagesInvoices;
use Laravel\Cashier\Concerns\ManagesPaymentMethods;
use Laravel\Cashier\Concerns\ManagesSubscriptions;
use App\Traits\Stripe\CustomPerformCharges as PerformsCharges;

trait CustomBillable
{
    use ManagesCustomer;
    use ManagesInvoices;
    use ManagesPaymentMethods;
    use ManagesSubscriptions;
    use PerformsCharges;
}
```

```
trait CustomPerformCharges
{
    use PerformsCharges;
  
    public function authorize(int $amount): Payment
    {
        if (!$this->hasStripeId()) {
            throw new BadRequestException(__('User is not a stripe customer'));
        }
        
        $paymentMethod = $this->defaultPaymentMethod();

        $options = [
            'capture_method' => 'manual'
        ];

        return $this->charge($amount, $paymentMethod, $options);
    }


    public function capture(int $amount, string $paymentIntent): void
    {
        $intent = StripePaymentIntent::retrieve($paymentIntent, $this->stripeOptions());
        $intent->capture(['amount_to_capture' => $amount]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: creating payment intents is possible now (checked with laravel 10.x)

Here is the link to official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/billing#creating-payment-intents

Copying below historic purposes

You can create a new Stripe payment intent by invoking the pay method on a billable model instance. Calling this method will create a payment intent that is wrapped in a `Laravel\Cashier\Payment` instance:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 
Route::post('/pay', function (Request $request) {
    $payment = $request->user()->pay(
        $request->get('amount')
    );
 
    return $payment->client_secret;
});
```

After creating the payment intent, you can return the client secret to your application's frontend so that the user can complete the payment in their browser.