# is there any way to create PaymentIntent from laravel cashier without using the raw create method

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I know I can create a `PaymentIntent` by doing

```php
PaymentIntent::create([])
```

but that requires pk authentication manually. I looked at the Cashier's `Billable` trait but found no such method, so I wonder if there's another to create it using Cashier's class.

Comment: all requests to the Stripe API requires a private/secret API key (with a few exceptions), so i'm not too sure what you're referring to by it requiring `pk authentication manually`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59530953/2718163 probably partially answers your question. Otherwise, if that doesn't suit your needs, you should use the stripe-php library : https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php

Comment: @alex Thank you anyway. I ended up using the raw `PaymentIntent::create` method instead of Cashier's method. And to address your first sentence, if you are using cashier, the private secret is added automatically from your .env file instead of manually configuring it like "Stripe::setApiKey()", that's the part I didn't want to do. But I couldn't find any solution, so I just did "Stripe::setApiKey".